# Accessing a SMTP/IMAP mailbox using powershell

Tags: powershell, smtp, imap

I need a library/API allowing me to connect to a SMTP/IMAP server with authentication using powershell.
I need to adapt a powershell script that uses EWS to access an Exchange server.
This Exchange Server will be shut down and we need to adapt that script for SMTP/IMAP.
This script looks into a mailbox for inbox and sent email and search some mail from their subjects using the EWS objects.

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried? anything you have looked into?

Comment: Well the fact is that i need an API or a library for Powershell to look into an IMAP account and send mail from this same acount via SMTP.

Comment: So is that a no....
I literally googled powershell IMAP and had responses...

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959668/get-email-using-powershell)

[Answer](http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/netcmdlets/)

Comment: Perhaps this will help?  Someone using PowerShell to access a C# IMAP library?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738457/translating-c-sharp-to-powershell-in-interimap

Comment: Thaks both of you. I'm gonna look both of your answers.
By the way, i didn't find the first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys, but i can't find what i need with the APIs you gave me.
Closing the question.